# Conflicting CSS - Can't set Div to sit at 50% of the page height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to set a div at 50% of the page's height using

```
.vertical-align-form-control {
min-height: 75%;
min-height: 75vh;
align-items: center;
}
```

My current code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/AjfUA26n
More at: http://infenterprises.com/contact/

I was able to apply this method to my About page without any problems. However, it appears that there is some sort of conflicting CSS that isn't allowing me to do the same with my Contact form.

Comment: Your title says 25% but your code says 75%

Comment: Setting it at 50% puts it at ~25% here: http://infenterprises.com/about/     I miss-titled and meant to put 50%. Anyways, if I set that page to min-height: 75%;, It sits at ~50%. The problem isn't that, it's that something isn't allowing the div to move in the first place.

Comment: can't open your site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have understood correctly what you want to achieve.

If not then just answer.

Here is my CSS code to resolve your problem:

```
.vertical-align-form-control {
    min-height: 75vh;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to set an element to be positioned at x position of screen that i dont see how min-height can be used to do that.

Normaly if you want for example to position an element to the bottom-right corner of the screen like a footer image for example then you could use:

```
.footer-img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

and so on.

Hope this helps to resolve your problem.